# Linking wiringPi Library with ROS2 service (serial) through CmakeLists.txt

Tags: ros2, c++

I have a ROS2 package where I want a client to ask for a location, and the server sends coordinates back over ethernet that it's gotten from a GPS board which connects to my raspberry pi via serial.

I've been able to handle the serial port side of things on my own (using `g++ <my c++ file> -lwiringPi`)

The ROS2 is for sending the data back to the client. The problem comes when I try to `colcon build` the package. I get the errors like

```
undefined reference to 'serialDataAvail'
undefined reference to 'serialGetchar'
undefined reference to 'wiringPiSetup'
...
```

for every wiringPi function referenced in the file.

I've tried putting in my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
find_package(wiringPi REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)

add_executable(server src/loc_serv.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(server rclcpp wiringPi)


install(TARGETS server DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

ament_package()
```

The errors are the same as if you were compiling with g++ and you forgot the `-lwiringPi` at the end, which makes me think I haven't linked the library correctly.

Does anybody know how to link the wiringPi library in the CMakeLists.txt file for use in a ROS2 project?

Answer (score 1):

## Replicated Error

I copied the `wiringPi.h` file from the GitHub and placed in an `include` directory in the package. Below are the relevant wiringPi references in the `CMakeList.txt`.

```
include_directories(include)

...

# The driver executable
add_executable(driver src/driver.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(
  driver
  geometry_msgs
  rclcpp
  tf2
  tf2_ros
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)
target_link_libraries(driver "${cpp_typesupport_target}" wiringPi)

...

install(
  DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include
)
```

I end up with this error when building which shows I haven't linked the library correctly.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwiringPi: No such file or directory
```

The flag `-lwiringPi` is used to link your program with the wiringPi library.

## Solution

```
# wiringPi
find_library(WIRINGPI_LIBRARY libwiringPi.so.2)

...

target_link_libraries(driver "${cpp_typesupport_target}" ${WIRINGPI_LIBRARY})
```

You can also hard-code the library path. If you don't want to use `find_library`.

```
target_link_libraries(driver "${cpp_typesupport_target}" /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwiringPi.so.2)
```

#### Resources

- https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/
- https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Ament-CMake-Documentation.html#adding-files-and-headers